# VB Set Checkbox on checked by default

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a small problem and I can't find a solution to that, I'll explain
How can I make a checkbox, by default, be checked instead of not?
I would need a solution that would also be able to save later if it is checked or not in my.settings

Comment: Perhaps you should add what kind of technology are you using. Checkboxes are controls available in WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET .... Also what do you mean with _saved_?

Comment: Yea sorry, WinForms

Comment: Click the checkbox on your form and then go to the checkbox properties. Set the Checked property to true. Save the form

Comment: You can also bind to a new or existing setting in the Properties window.

Comment: VB.NET programmers tend to not use `Public Sub New` often enough.  A constructor is important.  Just type it in, IntelliSense does the rest, append any code after the InitializeComponent() call.  The ideal place to use any saved settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Checkbox component to your Form, and in **Properties** window set **Checked** = true